# I can't find Install Guest additions option for virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed virtualbox 4.1.18 on Ubuntu 12.10 and I hosted windows XP.

I want to share a folder between Ubuntu and Windows XP, so I have read about it in [this external tread](http://www.nairabytes.net/ubuntu/virtualbox-shared-folder-on-an-ubuntu-host-and-a-windows-xp-guest).

The problem is when I'm trying to access to the *Install Guest additions* option I can't find the *Devices* menu, when I'm focusing the guest machine.

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: Have you tried uncapturing the mouse and then looking at the menu bar (When the window title "VirtualBox" is replaced by menus)?

Comment: yes I have tried this, now I found the option by pressing Host key + C

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to press the following keys: <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Are you certain about HOST + **C**? This is usually switching to scaled mode. Guest additions are mounted by HOST + **D**. See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox

Comment: yes I'm sure because I was asking about the Devices menu where I can find the Install Guest additions option

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and enter the command below to install It for VirtualBox 6x then reboot the vm

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```